# Deciding the clustering key snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As per the documentation we can select a column to for clustering based on the cardinality (distinct values of the column) and the column used in the join condition .Here is the o/p of clustering information for one of the table in the select query on which the query execution is taking more than 80%  of total execution time ( just to scan the table).FYI I have collected below output  for the table based on the column used in join condition.

Based on the o/p relating with my understanding .Below are the point make me  feel  that clustering the table based on the column in the subject will helps in increasing the performance .

ratio of total_partition_count 20955 to average_overlaps : 17151.4681
ratio of total_partition_count 20955 to average_depth : 16142.2524

1.Correct me if my understanding is wrong.(based on below facts is this table is a good candidate for clustering or not)?

Please also help with below other points as well

2.If i opt for clustering the table ,will it needs any downtime(or)does clustering adds up my bill?

3.Does this clustering impacts the future DML operations?

4.I see the select query is returning 23 rows after  scanning 37 GB of data ,what would be best solution to improve the performance of the query other than choosing clustering as an option.

Let me know for any details required

```
select SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION('tablename','(columnname)');
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(column used in join condition)",
  "total_partition_count" : 20955,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 2702,
  "average_overlaps" : 17151.4681,
  "average_depth" : 16142.2524,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 1933,
    "00002" : 0,
    "00003" : 0,
    "00004" : 0,
    "00005" : 0,
    "00006" : 0,
    "00007" : 0,
    "00008" : 0,
    "00009" : 0,
    "00010" : 0,
    "00011" : 0,
    "00012" : 0,
    "00013" : 0,
    "00014" : 0,
    "00015" : 0,
    "00016" : 0,
    "08192" : 2,
    "16384" : 3,
    "32768" : 19017
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a complex question that requires more information.  What is the query you are executing, what are the characteristics of each table, etc.?  If the largest amount of your query is the table scan, but you are not filtering in a WHERE clause on that filter, than clustering will not help you.  A larger warehouse would.  Provide more details.

Comment: Mike .Can you look at the output now. I edited the original post to show the output in a reader friendly way .Yes it depends on lost of factors.But can you help me with question 1  by cosidering the output

Answer (score 0):

1. a TABLE is a good candidate for clustering if the operation you care about "most" uses only a small number of rows than the total partitions read of which many are dropped by the filtering you would cluster by. Aka you are wasting $ reading data you don't want.

But you can only have one cluster on a table, so if you make one query better you might make others worse. Also

2. Auto-clustering does its work in the background, think of defragmentation of your harddrive. It's the same, and thus seems it is "work" yes you pay for it.
3. future DML is not directly impacted by clustering if you are mean will a future insert be N times slow because you have clustering on. But given you are altering data, there are two ways the DML multi impact your clustering, if you insert data is random sort, (with respect to your clustering) that data will be needed to be sort. Also you do you high frequency inserts this can interfere with the background clustering operations. Also the fact you insert new data to new partitions, the larger set needs reclustering.
4. You can rewrite the table with an ORDER BY  and do the clustering yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION data.

"average_overlaps" : 17151.4681 > 
Average number of overlapping micro-partitions for each micro-partition in the table. A high number indicates the table is not well-clustered.

"average_depth" : 16142.2524 > 
Average overlap depth of each micro-partition in the table. A high number indicates the table is not well-clustered.

The buckets 00000 through 32768 describe in how many micro-partitions (similar in concept to files) your cluster keys are split into.

"00000" : 0 > 
Zero (0) constant micro-partitions out of 20955 total micro-partitions.

"32768" : 19017 > The 32768 means that 32768 micro-partitions contain a cluster key.  19017 micro-partitions contain cluster keys that are also in up to 19017 other micro-partitions, which is bad because we'd need to scan all of these micro-partitions completely to find one of those cluster keys.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_clustering_information.html

1. As mentioned earlier Table would be good candidate for clustering if clustering keys are used in your queries like in selective filters or join predicates.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#strategies-for-selecting-clustering-keys

2.Automatic clustering works in the background and there no downtime required. As far as billing is concerned there will be some additional charges.

3.Clustering does not impact future DML operation as such but if there is constant DML operation on that table then as soon as the number of new micro partitions reach a certain threshold Automatic Clustering will start its operation to keep the table well clustered.

4. As mentioned by Simeon you can opt for rewriting the table with an ORDER BY and do the clustering yourself.